# Почему в данном случае вызов std::function такой медленный?

Tags: c++, функции

Ниже пример моей реализации. Не важно, что именно делают функции класса MyClass. Задача понять, насколько данная реализация хороша в плане производительности.

```
class MyFunctor
{
public:
    //MyFunctor(double (*func)()) : _func(func) {}; // can't do it
    MyFunctor(std::function<double(void)> func): _func(func) {};
    ~MyFunctor() {};

    double operator()() { return _func(); };

private:
    //double (*_func)();
    std::function<double(void)> _func;
    /*rest implementation*/
};


class MyClass1
{
    double _b{};
    double _c{};
    double _a{};

    vector<MyFunctor> _functors{};

    double func() { return (std::sin(_a) + std::cos(_b)); };
    double anotherFunc() { return _a * _a + _b * _b; };

public:
    MyClass1(double a) : _a(a), _b(a), _c(a)
    {
        _functors.push_back(MyFunctor{ [this]() {return func(); } });
        _functors.push_back(MyFunctor{ [this]() {return func() * func(); } });
        _functors.push_back(MyFunctor{ [this]() {return _a*anotherFunc(); } });
        _functors.push_back(MyFunctor{ [this]() {return _a + _b + _c; } });
    }

    vector<MyFunctor> getFunctors() { return _functors; }

    // FOR PERFORMANCE COMPARISON (do the same as functors)
    double F1() { return func(); };
    double F2() { return func() * func(); };
    double F3() { return _a*anotherFunc(); };
    double F4() { return _a + _b + _c; };

    ~MyClass1() {}
};

/*
 * .. i have many classes MyClass2, MyClass3, ... with getFunctors() function
 */

int main()
{
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using millisecond_t = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>;
    std::chrono::time_point<clock_t> tic;
    double elapsed;

    constexpr int N = 1000'000;

    MyClass1 C{ 1 };
    MyClass1 C2{ 2 };
    //MyClass2 D{ 3 }; // etc..

    auto functors = C.getFunctors(); // can also contain functors of other objects


    /* TEST FUNCTORS */
    double sum{};
    sum = 0.0;
    tic = clock_t::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;

        auto iter = functors.begin();
        while (iter != functors.end())
        {
            sum += (*iter)();
            ++iter;
        }
    }
    elapsed = duration_cast<millisecond_t>(clock_t::now() - tic).count();
    std::cout << "\t(functors) elapsed: " << elapsed << " millisec\t";
    std::cout << sum << "\n";


    /* TEST MEMBERS */
    sum = 0.0;
    tic = clock_t::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum = C.F1() + C.F2() + C.F3() + C.F4();
    }
    elapsed = duration_cast<millisecond_t>(clock_t::now() - tic).count();
    std::cout << "\t(members) elapsed: " << elapsed << " millisec\t";
    std::cout << sum << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
(functors) elapsed: 117.828 millisec    8.29107 
(members) elapsed: 1.4552 millisec      8.29107
```

В данном случае вызов функторов в ~100 раз медленнее, чем вызов напрямую методов класса.

msvc and gcc дают похожие результаты.

В моем приложении каждый функтор имеет несколько флагов, и в зависимости от значений этих флагов надо получить вектор значений функторов, удовлетворяющих некоторым условиям. Например, в функторах есть флаг, enable, и надо сформировать вектор double-ов - состоящий из значений функторов, для которых enable = true, или false. Получать такие векторы надо очень быстро после изменения флагов (на самом деле флаги - это состояния state machine).

Меня пугает такая разница в производительности, т.к. именно вычисление подобных функторов - основная нагрузка на производительность. А производительность на первом месте.

Стоит ли избегать в таких случаях std::function? Если да, то можно ли реализовать такую идею другим способом? Или проблема не в std::function, а в моей криворукости?
Т.к. опыта в C++ я только набираюсь, хотелось бы услышать советы от экспертов.

Спасибо.

UPD:
добавляю полный текст примера

```
// CMakeProject1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

class MyFunctor
{
public:
    //Eq(double (*func)()) : _func(func) {}; // can't do it
    MyFunctor(std::function<double(void)> func): _func(func) {};
    ~MyFunctor() {};

    double operator()() { return _func(); };

private:
    //double (*_func)();
    std::function<double(void)> _func;
    /*rest implementation*/
};


class MyClass1
{
    double _b{};
    double _c{};
    double _a{};

    vector<MyFunctor> _functors{};

    double func() { return (std::sin(_a) + std::cos(_b)); };
    double anotherFunc() { return _a * _a + _b * _b; };

public:
    MyClass1(double a) : _a(a), _b(a), _c(a)
    {
        _functors.push_back(MyFunctor{ [this]() {return func(); } });
        _functors.push_back(MyFunctor{ [this]() {return func() * func(); } });
        _functors.push_back(MyFunctor{ [this]() {return anotherFunc(); } });
        _functors.push_back(MyFunctor{ [this]() {return _a + _b + _c; } });
    }

    vector<MyFunctor> getFunctors() { return _functors; }

    double F1() { return func(); };
    double F2() { return func() * func(); };
    double F3() { return anotherFunc(); };
    double F4() { return _a + _b + _c; };

    ~MyClass1() {}
};

/*
 * .. i have many classes MyClass2, MyClass3 ...
 */

int main()
{
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using clock_t = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using millisecond_t = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>;
    std::chrono::time_point<clock_t> tic;
    double elapsed;

    constexpr int N = 1000'000;

    MyClass1 C{ 1 };
    MyClass1 C2{ 2 };
    //MyClass2 D{ 3 }; // etc..

    auto functors = C.getFunctors(); // also contains functors of other objects


    /* TEST FUNCTORS */
    double sum{};
    sum = 0.0;
    tic = clock_t::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        //for (auto& fu : functors)
        //    sum += fu();
        //sum = functors[0]() + functors[1]() + functors[2]() + functors[3]();

        auto iter = functors.begin();
        while (iter != functors.end())
        {
            sum += (*iter)();
            ++iter;
        }
    }
    elapsed = duration_cast<millisecond_t>(clock_t::now() - tic).count();
    std::cout << "\t(functors) elapsed: " << elapsed << " millisec\t";
    std::cout << sum << "\n";


    /* TEST MEMBERS */
    sum = 0.0;
    tic = clock_t::now();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        sum = C.F1() + C.F2() + C.F3() + C.F4();
    }
    elapsed = duration_cast<millisecond_t>(clock_t::now() - tic).count();
    std::cout << "\t(members) elapsed: " << elapsed << " millisec\t";
    std::cout << sum << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for CMakeProject1, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("CMakeProject1")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3")

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeProject1 
            "CMakeProject1.cpp"
            #"CMakeProject1.h"
            #"mvsignal.h"
            #"timer.h"
            )
```

Comment: это внушает оптимизм. Я запускаю под Visual Studio x64-Release. В CMAKE такие флаги set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17); set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3")

Comment: так же запускал под Ubuntu этот пример - такие же результаты...

Comment: Дайте [mre], чтобы можно было запустить у себя

Comment: добавил полный текст

Comment: Полный текст не нужен, нужен [mcve]. Прежде чем создавать такие вопросы следует убедится, что вы замеряете то, что нужно. А не бесполезное безостановочное копирование векторов и функторов.

Comment: В clang-e почти одинаково с O2, но чуть медленнее с O0 https://godbolt.org/z/e7zfWP

Comment: понял. Т.к. приложение содержит несколько тысяч строк кода, то с нуля получился такой кривой, возможно, пример. Постараюсь реализовать что-то более конкретное, если этого недостаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В медленном варианте вы вызываете функции не прямо, а из массива указателей на функции. Так как этот массив функций может в любой момент поменять значения указателей на функции оптимизатор ничего не может ускорить, а выполняет то что вы написали. Ассемблер :

```
.L135:
    movq    24(%rsp), %rbx  # MEM[(struct MyFunctor * const &)&functors], ivtmp.321
# functory.cpp:84:         sum = 0;
    movq    $0x000000000, (%rsp)    #, %sfp
.L134:
# functory.cpp:90:         while (iter != functors.end())
    cmpq    %rbx, 32(%rsp)  # ivtmp.321, MEM[(struct MyFunctor * const &)&functors + 8]
    je  .L132   #,
# /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:704:       if (_M_empty())
    cmpq    $0, 16(%rbx)    #, MEM[base: iter$_M_current_40, offset: 16B]
    jne .L133   #,
.LEHB26:
# /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:705:   __throw_bad_function_call();
    call    _ZSt25__throw_bad_function_callv    #
.L133:
# /usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:706:       return _M_invoker(_M_functor, std::forward<_ArgTypes>(__args)...);
    movq    %rbx, %rdi  # ivtmp.321,
    call    *24(%rbx)   # MEM[base: iter$_M_current_40, offset: 24B]
# functory.cpp:92:             sum += (*iter)();
    addsd   (%rsp), %xmm0   # %sfp, _88
    addq    $32, %rbx   #, ivtmp.321
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rsp)   # _88, %sfp
    jmp .L134   #
.L132:
# functory.cpp:82:     for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    decq    %rbp    # ivtmp_43
    jne .L135   #,
```

Быстрый вариант :

```
# functory.cpp:49:     double F1() { return func(); };
    leaq    48(%rsp), %rdi  #, tmp194
# functory.cpp:103:     tic = clock_t::now();
    movq    %rax, %rbx  #, tic
# functory.cpp:49:     double F1() { return func(); };
    call    _ZN8MyClass14funcEv #
# functory.cpp:36:     double anotherFunc() { return _a * _a + _b * _b; };
    movsd   64(%rsp), %xmm1 # C._a, _97
    movsd   48(%rsp), %xmm3 # C._b, _99
    movaps  %xmm1, %xmm2    # _97, tmp155
    movaps  %xmm3, %xmm4    # _99, tmp156
    mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm2    # _97, tmp155
# functory.cpp:52:     double F4() { return _a + _b + _c; };
    addsd   %xmm3, %xmm1    # _99, tmp161
# functory.cpp:36:     double anotherFunc() { return _a * _a + _b * _b; };
    mulsd   %xmm3, %xmm4    # _99, tmp156
# functory.cpp:52:     double F4() { return _a + _b + _c; };
    addsd   56(%rsp), %xmm1 # C._c, tmp162
# functory.cpp:36:     double anotherFunc() { return _a * _a + _b * _b; };
    addsd   %xmm4, %xmm2    # tmp156, tmp157
# functory.cpp:50:     double F2() { return func() * func(); };
    movaps  %xmm0, %xmm4    # _63, tmp158
    mulsd   %xmm0, %xmm4    # _63, tmp158
# functory.cpp:106:         sum = C.F1() + C.F2() + C.F3() + C.F4();
    addsd   %xmm4, %xmm0    # tmp158, tmp159
    addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0    # tmp157, tmp160
    addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0    # tmp162, tmp160
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rsp)   # tmp160, %sfp
```

Все математические операции выполняются прямо по тексту, не смотря на адреса функций (они вызываются статически). И самое главное: оптимизатор миллион раз передумал всё вычислять (бессмысленно). Оставил только одну итерацию, без цикла.

Пугаться скорости не надо. Если надо, чтобы массив функций был динамическим, меняя адреса функций, то так и быть. Пользуйтесь вектором.

Comment: огромное спасибо! Наконец-то развернутый ответ. Я понял, что пример не показательный и может не отражать реальную проблему, но понять почему в данном случае компилятор ведет себя так - очень полезно. С первого взгляда - вроде делам одно и то же... Попытаюсь разобрать приведенный Вами код. Следующий вопрос - использование, например, std::deque в данном случае не поможет компилятору? Там же, в отличие от вектора, указатели не ломаются. Или я не до конца понял проблему?

Comment: но самое главное - я понял, что этот вариант жизнеспособный. А то я несколько раз натыкался на упоминание того, что std::function довольно "дорогИ" в плане производительности. И первая попытка замера меня, мягко говоря, смутила